Divisors on a projective bundle
Let us consider $E$ to be the trivial bundle of rank $3$ on $\mathbb P^2$. Consider the  projection map $\pi: X=\mathbb P(E) \to \mathbb P^2$. Let $H$ to be the relative hyperplane divisor corresponding to $ \mathcal O_{\mathbb P(E)}(1)$ and $F$ to be the divisor corresponding to $\pi^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(1))$.
Now $X$ can also be thought of as $\mathbb P^2 \times \mathbb P^2$ and thus there are two projection maps $p_1$ and $p_2$ from $X$ to $\mathbb P^2$. Let $\mathcal O_X(a,b):=p_1^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(a)) \otimes  p_2^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(b))$.
Then my question is what line bundle $\mathcal O_X(a,b)$ one obtains corresponding to the divisor lets say $-2F-H$? is it $\mathcal O_X(-1,-2)$?
